# Configuring Java security policy to allow JUnit?

Tags: java, java-security

I am developing a Java application.  I want to run its unit tests in a security-restricted JVM so as to block network access.

I added `-Djava.security.manager=default -Djava.security.policy=...file...` options to the JVM, and the security manager is effective.

I iterated a couple of times by running my tests, seeing what security violation happens, and granting it in the policy file.  But now, I am not getting any security violations anymore.  Instead, this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.onebusaway.alexa.AuthedSpeechletTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.143 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.onebusaway.alexa.AuthedSpeechletTest
org.onebusaway.alexa.AuthedSpeechletTest  Time elapsed: 0.06 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:364)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)

Running org.onebusaway.alexa.MainSpeechletEmptyTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.onebusaway.alexa.MainSpeechletEmptyTest
org.onebusaway.alexa.MainSpeechletEmptyTest  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:364)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)


Results :

Tests in error:
  JUnit4Provider.invoke:161->executeTestSet:238->executeWithRerun:274->execute:364 » NoClassDefFound
  JUnit4Provider.invoke:161->executeTestSet:238->executeWithRerun:274->execute:364 » NoClassDefFound

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
```

How do I see exactly what security policy is violated here?  (I tried rerunning with `-X`, but that didn't reveal anything new.)

Comment: This doesn't look like a security violation. Are you sure you have JUnit as a dependency in your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, here's the branch: https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-alexa/tree/unit-test-network-access. Compare to `master`.

Comment: You're quite right. I've tried a lot of permutations in the policy file, and the only one I can get to work is java.security.AllPermission. This is obviously not that helpful, but it points out that it's definitely a security issue.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to look into it. I appreciate the discovery.

Comment: You can use -Djava.security.debug=all in your pom.xml to view more debug information. I'm out of ideas for now.